# Write SQL Statement against Oracle Cloud Database Schema services using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I have a subscription to Oracle Cloud Database Schema Services ( Schema not full Database ) , I am trying to access the database instance using Oracle SQL Developer , I followed the below to make connection in SQL developer :

1 - From "Database schema Service connection"

2 - New Cloud Connection and enter my username/password/instance URL

3- The database connected and I can list all tables inside the schema

But When I tried to open SQL worksheet and write some select statements , I can't achieve this.

I know that this task can be done through APEX console , but is there anyway to do it by using SQL Developer?

Comment: Did you follow instructions described in "Accessing a Database Cloud Service instance using Oracle SQL Developer", here: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/paas/accessdbinstance/accessdbinstance.html#section1s1

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported.

The SCHEMA service is only reachable via HTTPS. We have built several REST Services that allow SQL Developer to do what you see currently today, which includes browsing the schema and uploading data via the CART.

We have just built a SQL 'REST Service' feature into Oracle REST Data Services which allow us..or any authenticated user, to run an ad-hoc SQL or PL/SQL block statement via a POST. This would allow us to add what you're looking for - the ability to do a SQL Worksheet for your service.

However, instead of building this into the SQL Developer desktop, we're looking at releasing 'SQL Developer Web' which will be available in your Oracle Cloud Database Services' consoles.

I can't tell you if/when that will be available for you in your Schema Service, but it's on the road map.

In the mean time, the APEX UI and its SQL Workshop is the way to go.